# Why does inserting a function inside a route differ from inserting the code inside the function in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am trying to make a web app with a login system. I want to make it so that a user can't access certain pages unless they are logged in.

What I want is that when you click to go to another page while not logged in, you get redirected to the login page and on it you get a message flash.

This is what works:

```
@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    #some form
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        flash('You need to be logged in to access this page.', 'info')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    #rest of the code
```

But I would need to add all of this to other routes as well. So I created the function and added it to the routes instead:

```
@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    #some form
    require_login()
    #rest of the code

def require_login():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        flash('You need to be logged in to access this page.', 'info')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

But this does not work as I want it to. It instead redirects to the home page and then flashes the message. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `redirect(...)` doesn't itself do the redirect.  It returns a value to Flask telling flask that it needs to do the redirect.

In your first piece of code, you handle this correctly.  You take the result of `redirect(...)` and return it to flask.  In your second piece of code, you take the redirection returned by `require_login` and ignore it in `home`.

You might try something like:

```
value = require_login()
if value:
     return value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the function

```
return require_login()
```

But be aware, after that u cant have code. You should create an decorator for this. There are examples online just Google "flask authorized decorator"

Your Advantage of this that u can move the auth Logic out of the Views and you can easily decorate your Views and dont have this Stuff in each View/route